# How to get latest category on magento 1.9.2.4?

Tags: magento-1.9, category

In Magento 1.9: I have to show latest added **category's description** on **template**.

So how to get **latest category**?

Answer (score 1):

you can sort category by `created_at`

```
$collection=Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection();
$collection->getSelect()->order('created_at DESC');
$collection->getFirstItem();
```